# Get name of active Excel workbook from Python

Tags: python, com

I am trying to write a Python script that will access and modify the active Excel workbook using the Excel COM interface. However, I am having difficulty getting this to work when there are multiple Excel instances running. For example, the code

```
import win32com.client

xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
print(xl.ActiveWorkbook.FullName)
```

prints out the name of the active workbook from the first running instance of Excel only. What I really want is the workbook that I last clicked on, regardless of what Excel instance it was in.

Thanks.

Comment: not an answer. Did you consider using xlrd, xlwt? It seems to me more transparent than win32com

Comment: Will the instance of Excel that you want be the currently active window when this runs?

Comment: jaoquin - those modules are not for interprocess communication, which is what I need here. The target workbook will be open and it needs to react and real time to the commands being issued from the Python program.

tgray - Sorry, I am not sure I understand your question. Basically I want the active book to be the last workbook that I had focus on. The workbook will naturally still be open when I run my program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT FOR COMMENTS**

There might be a better way to do this.

Install the excellent [psutil](http://code.google.com/p/psutil)

```
import psutil
excelPids = []
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
  if proc.name == "EXCEL.EXE": excelPids.append(proc.pid)
```

Now enumerate the windows, but get the window title and pid.

```
windowPidsAndTitle = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(lambda hwnd, resultList: resultList.append((win32gui.GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd),win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd))), windowPidsAndTitle)
```

Now just find the first pid that is in our excelPids

```
  for pid,title in windowPidsAndTitle:
    if pid in excelPids:
      return title
```

**END EDITS**

There is a number of things to take into consideration here:

Does one instance have multiple workbooks open?  In this case

```
xl = win32com.client.Dispatch("Excel.Application")
xl.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Will indeed give you the last active workbook.

Or are there separate instances of EXCEL.EXE running?  [You can get each instance with](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288902):

```
xl = win32com.client.GetObjec(None, "Excel.Application") #instance one
xl = win32com.client.GetObject("Name_Of_Workbook") #instance two
```

But this defeats the purpose because you need to know the name AND this will not tell you which one last had focus.

To @tgrays comment above, if your excel instance is guaranteed to be the foreground window then:

```
import win32gui
win32gui.GetWindowText(win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()) 
#parse this and use GetObject to get your excel instance
```

But worst case scenerio, multiple instances and you have to find which had focus last, you'll have to enumerate all the windows and find the one you care about:

```
windows = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(lambda hwnd, resultList: resultList.append(win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd)),windows)
#enumerates all the windows open from the top down
[i for i in windows if "Microsoft Excel" in i].pop(0)
#this one is closest to the top
```

Good luck with this one!

Comment: Thanks very much Mark, this worked. I just had one follow on question. It is possible a window which has the text "Microsoft Excel" in its title but that is not an Excel window could be returned. Indeed, I thought of this because I actually had a PDF open with those words in its title. Is there a way to check that the window we get back is in fact a reference to an Excel application?

Answer (score 4):

With xlwings you can simply do:

```
import xlwings as xw
print(xw.books.active.name)
```

This will correctly work even if you have multiple instances of Excel open.