# How do I use python pandas to read an already opened excel sheet

Tags: python, excel, pandas

Assuming I have an excel sheet already open, make some changes in the file and use pd.read_excel to create a dataframe based on that sheet, I understand that the dataframe will only reflect the data in the last saved version of the excel file. I would have to save the sheet first in order for pandas dataframe to take into account the change.

Is there anyway for pandas or other python packages to read an opened excel file and be able to refresh its data real time (without saving or closing the file)?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876755/get-name-of-active-excel-workbook-from-python).

Comment: Assuming one is using Windows or MacOS, [`xlwings`](https://www.xlwings.org/) may do the work.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do this. The table is not saved to disk, so `pandas` can not read it from disk.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using `mitosheet` package? *It doesn't answer your question directly*, but it allows you working on pandas dataframes as you would do in excel sheets. In this way, you may edit the data on the fly as in excel and still get a pandas dataframe as a result (meanwhile generating the code to perform the same operations with python). Does this help?

Answer (score 0):

Be careful not to over-engineer, that being said:

Depending on your use case, if this is really needed, I could theoretically imagine a Robotic Process Automation like e.g. BluePrism, UiPath or PowerAutomate loading live data from Excel into a Python environment with a pandas DataFrame continuously and then changing it.

This use case would have to be a really important process though, otherwise licensing RPA is not worth it here.

Answer (score 0):

df = pd.read_excel("path")

In variable explorer you can see the data if you run the program in SPYDER ide