# Using the active workbook in python script with openpyxl?

Tags: python, excel, vba, openpyxl

I am trying to run a python script from a vba excel macro. I am using openpyxl

I have a button in my custom ribbon calling the sub-RunPythonScript ()

```
Set objShell = VBA.CreateObject("Wscript.Shell")
objShell.Run sPathPythonExe & sPathPythonScript & sPythonScriptFileName
```

This works because I have  hardcoded the full path of the xls I want to use (for testing)

```
TheFilePathXLS = r'C:\Users\aa\bb\cc\targetxls.xlsx'
thetargetxlswb = openpyxl.load_workbook(TheFilePathXLS)
```

I would like to change this so that the python script picks up the (open) active worksheet. How do I do that?
In the vba macro, I can set up  a simple line to get the top active workbook full path

```
TheFilePathXLS = ActiveWorkbook.FullName
```

Do I need to pass this as an argument? if so what is the best/easiest way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a bit harder than this because to achieve what you want, you don't need to manipulate your Excel file but your Excel application instance. Have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2876755/get-name-of-active-excel-workbook-from-python